# Basic settings, custom error page, dynamic versioning, rewrite rules

Tags: php, html5, .htaccess

Any suggestion is more than welcome! I had to do a few tricks in rewrite rules (checks on `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS`) to avoid infinite loops, but it works fine.

**error.php**

```
<?php

$code = 0;

if (isset($_GET['code']))
    $code = (int)$_GET['code'];
else if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']))
    $code = (int)$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'];

switch ($code)  
{
    case 400:
        $message = 'Bad Request';
        break;

    case 401:
        $message = 'Unauthorized';
        break;

    case 402:
        $message = 'Payment Required';
        break;

    case 403:
        $message = 'Forbidden';
        break;

    case 404:
        $message = 'Not Found';
        break;

    case 405:
        $message = 'Method Not Allowed';
        break;

    case 406:
        $message = 'Not Acceptable';
        break;

    case 407:
        $message = 'Proxy Authentication Required';
        break;

    case 408:
        $message = 'Request Timeout';
        break;

    case 409:
        $message = 'Conflict';
        break;

    case 410:
        $message = 'Gone';
        break;

    case 411:
        $message = 'Length Required';
        break;

    case 412:
        $message = 'Precondition Failed';
        break;

    case 413:
        $message = 'Request Entity Too Large';
        break;

    case 414:
        $message = 'Request-URI Too Long';
        break;

    case 415:
        $message = 'Unsupported Media Type';
        break;

    case 416:
        $message = 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable';
        break;

    case 417:
        $message = 'Expectation Failed';
        break;

    case 418:
        $message = 'I\'m a Teapot';
        break;

    case 421:
        $message = 'Misdirected Request';
        break;

    case 422:
        $message = 'Unprocessable Entity';
        break;

    case 423:
        $message = 'Locked';
        break;

    case 424:
        $message = 'Failed Dependency';
        break;

    case 425:
        $message = 'Unordered Collection';
        break;

    case 426:
        $message = 'Upgrade Required';
        break;

    case 428:
        $message = 'Precondition Required';
        break;

    case 429:
        $message = 'Too Many Requests';
        break;

    case 431:
        $message = 'Request Header Fields Too Large';
        break;

    case 451:
        $message = 'Unavailable For Legal Reasons';
        break;

    case 500:
        $message = 'Internal Server Error';
        break;

    case 501:
        $message = 'Not Implemented';
        break;

    case 502:
        $message = 'Bad Gateway';
        break;

    case 503:
        $message = 'Service Unavailable';
        break;

    case 504:
        $message = 'Gateway Timeout';
        break;

    case 505:
        $message = 'HTTP Version Not Supported';
        break;

    case 506:
        $message = 'Variant Also Negotiates';
        break;
    case 507:
        $message = 'Insufficient Storage';
        break;

    case 508:
        $message = 'Loop Detected';
        break;

    case 509:
        $message = 'Bandwidth Limit Exceeded';
        break;

    case 510:
        $message = 'Not Extended';
        break;

    case 511:
        $message = 'Network Authentication Required';
        break;

    default:
        $code = '???';
        $message = 'Unknown Error';
        break;
}

echo $code.' '.$message;

?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
############
# SETTINGS #
############

Options All +FollowSymlinks -ExecCGI -Indexes -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php
DirectorySlash On
IndexIgnore *

SetEnv TZ [Your Time Zone]

############
# BROWSERS #
############

BrowserMatch MSIE\ 6\. image-toolbar
BrowserMatch MSIE\ (?:8|9|10)\. legacy-document

Header set imagetoolbar "no" env=image-toolbar
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge,chrome=1" env=legacy-document

<FilesMatch "\.(?:atom|bin|bmp|css|cur|eot|exe|gif|g?zip|gz|ico|jp(?:eg?|g)|js(?:on)?|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|svgz?|swf|tiff?|tt[cf]|txt|webp|woff2?|xml)$">
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible env=legacy-document
</FilesMatch>

###################
# FILES - CACHING #
###################

FileETag None

Header unset ETag
Header unset Pragma

ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault A2592000

# Data Interchange Files
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      A3600
ExpiresByType application/json          A0
ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml       A3600
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       A3600
ExpiresByType application/xml           A0

# Image Files
ExpiresByType image/bmp             A31536000
ExpiresByType image/gif             A31536000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg            A31536000
ExpiresByType image/png             A31536000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml         A31536000
ExpiresByType image/tiff            A31536000
ExpiresByType image/webp            A31536000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon          A31536000

# Script Files
ExpiresByType application/javascript        A31536000

# Style Files
ExpiresByType text/css              A31536000

# Other Files
ExpiresByType text/html             A0

#######################
# FILES - COMPRESSION #
#######################

SetEnvIfNoCase ^(?:Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^(?:(?:gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ has-accept-encoding
RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=has-accept-encoding

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/bmp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/tiff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain

AddEncoding gzip .svgz

####################
# FILES - ENCODING #
####################

AddLanguage en .atom
AddLanguage en .css
AddLanguage en .js
AddLanguage en .json
AddLanguage en .rdf
AddLanguage en .rss
AddLanguage en .txt
AddLanguage en .xml

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .atom
AddCharset UTF-8 .css
AddCharset UTF-8 .js
AddCharset UTF-8 .json
AddCharset UTF-8 .rdf
AddCharset UTF-8 .rss
AddCharset UTF-8 .xml

####################
# FILES - HANDLERS #
####################

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js

######################
# FILES - MIME TYPES #
######################

# Archive Files
AddType application/x-gzip      .gz .gzip
AddType application/zip         .zip

# Data Interchange Files
AddType application/atom+xml        .atom
AddType application/json        .json
AddType application/rdf+xml     .rdf
AddType application/rss+xml     .rss
AddType application/xml         .xml

# Font Files
AddType application/font-woff       .woff
AddType application/font-woff2      .woff2
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject   .eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf      .ttc .ttf
AddType font/opentype           .otf

# Image Files
AddType image/bmp           .bmp
AddType image/gif           .gif
AddType image/jpeg          .jpe .jpeg .jpg
AddType image/png           .png
AddType image/svg+xml           .svg .svgz
AddType image/tiff          .tif .tiff
AddType image/webp          .webp
AddType image/x-icon            .cur .ico

# Media Files
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash   .swf
AddType audio/ogg           .oga .ogg .opus
AddType video/ogg           .ogv

# Script Files
AddType application/javascript      .js

# Style Files
AddType text/css            .css

# Text Files
AddType application/pdf         .pdf
AddType text/plain          .txt

# Other Files
AddType application/octet-stream    .bin .exe

###########################
# SECURITY - CROSS-ORIGIN #
###########################

<FilesMatch "\.(?:bmp|cur|gif|ico|jp(?:eg?|g)|png|svgz?|tiff?|webp)$">
    SetEnvIf Origin ":" is-cors
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=is-cors
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(?:eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

#####################
# SECURITY - ERRORS #
#####################

ErrorDocument 400 /error/400/
ErrorDocument 401 /error/401/
ErrorDocument 402 /error/402/
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403/
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404/
ErrorDocument 405 /error/405/
ErrorDocument 406 /error/406/
ErrorDocument 407 /error/407/
ErrorDocument 408 /error/408/
ErrorDocument 409 /error/409/
ErrorDocument 410 /error/410/
ErrorDocument 411 /error/411/
ErrorDocument 412 /error/412/
ErrorDocument 413 /error/413/
ErrorDocument 414 /error/414/
ErrorDocument 415 /error/415/
ErrorDocument 416 /error/416/
ErrorDocument 417 /error/417/
ErrorDocument 422 /error/422/
ErrorDocument 423 /error/423/
ErrorDocument 424 /error/424/
ErrorDocument 426 /error/426/
ErrorDocument 428 /error/428/
ErrorDocument 429 /error/429/
ErrorDocument 431 /error/431/
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500/
ErrorDocument 501 /error/501/
ErrorDocument 502 /error/502/
ErrorDocument 503 /error/503/
ErrorDocument 504 /error/504/
ErrorDocument 505 /error/505/
ErrorDocument 506 /error/506/
ErrorDocument 507 /error/507/
ErrorDocument 508 /error/508/
ErrorDocument 510 /error/510/
ErrorDocument 511 /error/511/

############################
# SECURITY - MISCELLANEOUS #
############################

Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header unset Server
Header unset X-Powered-By

LimitRequestBody 1048576

ServerSignature Off

############
# REWRITES #
############

# Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Security: Protected Resources
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?:/|^)\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?:ba?k|cfg|conf|dist|fla|in[ci](?:\.php)?|info|log|po|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^#.*#$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ~$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

# Security: Vulnerabilities
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} (?:DELETE|DEBUG|HEAD|TRACE|TRACK) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (?:\\n|\\r|%00|%0A|%0D|cgi-bin|etc/passwd) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (?:/\*|\?)\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:/self/|cPath=) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:127\.0\.0\.1|localhost|loopback) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:<|%3C).*(?:embed|iframe|object|script|(?:[^e]*e)+mbed|(?:[^i]*i)+frame|(?:[^o]*o)+bject|(?:[^s]*s)+cript).*(?:>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:\.{1,}/)+(?:bin|etc|motd) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:\.|%2E)(?:\.|%2E)(?:/|%2F) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:\\n|\\r|%00|%0A|%0D) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:BASE64_(?:EN|DE)CODE|LOAD_FILE|MD5|OUTFILE|SHA1|SP_EXECUTESQL) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:CONCAT[^\(]*\(|UNION(?:(?:[^A]*A)+LL)?(?:[^S]*S)+ELECT) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:ftp|https?)(?::|%3A)(?:/|%2F)?(?:/|%2F)? [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:GLOBALS|_REQUEST)(?:=|\[|\%[a-z0-9]{0,2}) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =\|w\| [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =PHP[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12} [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-z0-9_]=(?:(?:\.\.//?)+|/(?:[a-z0-9._]//?)$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-z_]{1,21}(?:=|%3D) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} proc/self/environ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

# Cosmetics: Remove WWW Subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Cosmetics: Remove Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* $0 [R=301,L]

# Cosmetics: Remove PHP Extension
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !(?:^4|^5)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ .*\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Cosmetics: Remove Index
RewriteRule ^(.*)index/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Cosmetics: Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [R=301,L]

# Functions: Dynamic Versioning
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.[0-9]+\.(bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jp(?:eg?|g)|js|png|svgz?|tiff?|webp)$ $1.$2 [L]

# Functions: Pretty URLs
RewriteRule ^error/([^/]+)/$ /error.php?code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^threads/([0-9]+)/$ /thread.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/$ /users.php?id=$1 [L]

# Functions: Resources Lookup
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.*/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1\.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, as I'm not that guru about Apache (and your `.htaccess` covers a lot of cases).

But merely regarding your `error.php` script, I suggest a reduced code, improving maintainability:

```
$messages = [
  400 => 'Bad Request',
  401 => 'Unauthorized',
  402 => 'Payment Required',
  403 => 'Forbidden',
  404 => 'Not Found',
  405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
  406 => 'Not Acceptable',
  407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
  408 => 'Request Timeout',
  409 => 'Conflict',
  410 => 'Gone',
  411 => 'Length Required',
  412 => 'Precondition Failed',
  413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
  414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
  415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
  416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
  417 => 'Expectation Failed',
  418 => 'I\'m a Teapot',
  421 => 'Misdirected Request',
  422 => 'Unprocessable Entity',
  423 => 'Locked',
  424 => 'Failed Dependency',
  425 => 'Unordered Collection',
  426 => 'Upgrade Required',
  428 => 'Precondition Required',
  429 => 'Too Many Requests',
  431 => 'Request Header Fields Too Large',
  451 => 'Unavailable For Legal Reasons',
  500 => 'Internal Server Error',
  501 => 'Not Implemented',
  502 => 'Bad Gateway',
  503 => 'Service Unavailable',
  504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
  505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported',
  506 => 'Variant Also Negotiates',
  507 => 'Insufficient Storage',
  508 => 'Loop Detected',
  509 => 'Bandwidth Limit Exceeded',
  510 => 'Not Extended',
  511 => 'Network Authentication Required',
  '???' => 'Unknown Error',
];
array_key_exists(
  ($code =
    @$_GET['code'] ? $_GET['code'] : (
      @$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] ? $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] : 0)
    ), $messages ? $code : '???'
);
echo $code . ' ' . $messages[$code];
```

You may note the use of `@`: I know there is an eternal controversy about it, but I'm firmly partisan of using it in a few clearly identified cases such this one (i.e. when the only "error" which may happen and be masked is just the equivalent of `isset()`).